# Retrieving DV-cam info using Expression Encoder 4 SDK

Tags: .net-4.0, expression-encoder, expression-encoder-sdk

I am developing a Windows Forms application in .NET Framework 4.0 which controls a DV-CAM using the Expression Encoder 4 SDK. In the past I used Windows Media Encoder for this, but I would like to upgrade to Expression Encoder, because it seems a lot more solid.

Overall, the SDK is working great, I can control and view the DV-CAM video using a LiveDeviceSource and LiveJob. But it seems a few features are missing (or I just can't find them). I use the following code to setup the connection with the DV-CAM:

```
HandleRef handleRef = new HandleRef(videoPanel, videoPanel.Handle);
_preview = new PreviewWindow(handleRef);
_job = new LiveJob();

Collection devices = EncoderDevices.FindDevices(EncoderDeviceType.Video);
if (devices.Count > 0)
  _device = devices[0];

if (_device != null)
{
  _source = _job.AddDeviceSource(_device, _device); // init a LiveDeviceSource
  _source.PreviewWindow = _preview;
  _job.ActivateSource(_source);
}
```

This all works fine. But I can't seem to find the current framerate and current status of the DV-CAM. I can get the total framerates by using:

```
_source.SourcePropertiesSnapshot().TotalFrames;
```

But this will keep increasing, even when the DV-CAM is paused. So I have the following questions:

- How can I get the current frame position of the DV-CAM?
- How can I get the current status (Playing/Paused/End of Tape etc) of the DV-CAM?

Thanks!